# Debezium and Float data type

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a float data type in MySQL
I tried all the decimal converters, but every time, I'm getting a wrong value

Source data type `float(3,2)`

Value inserted: `32.43`

Value from Kafka topic: `9.99`

Any idea why the conversion is not happening properly?

### Update: 2021-07-26

I found that this is from MySQL side because MySQL itself stores this value in that format. Even binlog stores it as `9.99` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka or Debezium didn't generate this issue, it is from MySQL. I checked the table and binlog, the value was 9.99 only.

#### Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `point` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into table2 values (29,'bbb',32.43);

select * from table1;
| 29 | bbb  |  9.99 |
```

But there was a warning.

```
Out of range value for column 'point' at row 1
```

### Credits:

I asked this question in MySQL's slack community. **Graham Halsey** helped me to understand this issue.

```
float(3,2) means you can store 3 digits, 2 of which are after the decimal point
```